# AIX SSH with Pipe operation one liners fail

Tags: ssh, sed, pipe, aix

I have a one liner to collect the *errpt* information on each AIX VIO server using `ssh`. But the below command is not working. I'm piping the command to execute on root shell on VIO server (oem_setup_env)

```
ssh -padmin@VIOS1 "print \"errpt -T PERM,TEMP  -s 0610141418 -e 0701000018 \| awk -F " " '{print \$5,\$6,\$7,\$8,\$9}'\ | sort -u | sed -e "s/^/$(uname -n): /"\" | oem_setup_env"
```

Getting below error.

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/^/VIOS1: cannot be parsed.
```

Comment: this may be related https://serverfault.com/questions/317395/aix-sed-parsing-error-0602-404-but-works-with-linux-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your quoting all messed-up. It's easier to make the text to feed `oem_setup_env` locally and transfer it over `ssh`:

```
ssh admin@VIOS1 oem_setup_env << 'EOF'
errpt -T PERM,TEMP  -s 0610141418 -e 0701000018 |
    awk '{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' | sort -u | sed "s/^/$(uname -n): /"
EOF
```

To make it remotely, it's still easier to use a here document (than using `print` which is `ksh`/`zsh` specific and needs `-r` to avoid interpreting backslashes) to avoid two many levels of quote escaping:

```
ssh admin@VIOS1 'oem_setup_env << "EOF"
errpt -T PERM,TEMP  -s 0610141418 -e 0701000018 |
    awk '\''{print $5,$6,$7,$8,$9}'\'' | sort -u | sed "s/^/$(uname -n): /"
EOF'
```

Comment: Many thanks for giving the solution @stephane Chazelas's. The solution worked perfectly

Comment: if i want to pass a variable for flags -s and -e . Could you suggest if that would be possible. errpt -T PERM,TEMP  -s $VAR1 -e $VAR2