# AIX restricted shell add entry to inittab

Tags: shell-script, ssh, ksh, aix, restricted-shell

Need a help in adding an entry to the AIX inittab on VIO server. The VIO server is a restricted shell, to add entry to the inittab we need to access the root shell using command: `oem_setup_env`. I'm trying to add the below entry using SSH from Jump Server to the VIO server. The entry doesn't get added to inittab file.

```
ssh -q aixlpar122 "ssh -q padmin@vio01 print "\mkitab \"splunk:2:once:/usr/bin/startsrc\ -g\ splunk\ \>\ \/dev\/console\ 2\>\&1\ "  | oem_setup_env "
```

Getting below error :

```
rksh: /dev/console: 0403-019 The operation is not allowed in a restricted shell.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending [Stéphane's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) idea from a [previous answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453050/117549):

```sh
ssh -q aixlpar122 ssh -q padmin@vio01 oem_setup_env << 'EOF'
mkitab "splunk:2:once:/usr/bin/startsrc -g splunk > /dev/console 2>&1"
EOF
```

This:

1. starts an ssh session to aixlpar122 with a single command (another `ssh`) whose input is redirected from the here-document given at the end.
2. the second ssh session to padmin@vio01 starts a single command (`oem_setup_env`) who will receive (consume) commands from stdin.
3. the here-document sends the normally-quoted `mkitab` command along the ssh chain.

Hopefully the Splunk you have is the Splunk from the [VIOS Recognized Solutions page](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/VIOS%20Recognized/page/VIOS%20Recognized%20Solutions) and that your inittab entry isn't clobbered by future VIOS upgrades!