# how to use quotes in sed & ssh?

Tags: ssh, sed, quoting

i cant get this to work in bash/rhel 7:

```
ssh host "sed -i -e \"s/dnl MASQUERADE_AS.*\$/MASQUERADE_AS(\`domain.com\')dnl/\" /etc/mail/sendmail.mc"

bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

i essentially want this sed which works on a regular command line but breaks within ssh:

```
sed -i -e "s/dnl MASQUERADE_AS.*$/MASQUERADE_AS(\`domain.com\')dnl/" /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
```

anyone have any ideas? much appreciated.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a backtick? That's the start of the shell command substitution syntax. Quoting hell is no fun: try this ``ssh host 'sed -i -e "s/dnl MASQUERADE_AS.*\$/MASQUERADE_AS(\`domain.com'\'')dnl/" /etc/mail/sendmail.mc'
``

Comment: @glennjackman sendmail.mc is under m4 macro assembler, it might be using a peculiar syntax.

Comment: Consider using a quoted here-string as input to `ssh host` -- see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453050/117549 as one example

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jeff's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554477/how-to-use-quotes-in-sed-ssh#comment1029789_554477) of using a here-document for the `sed` script itself (well, he mentions a "here-string", but you'd have issues with quoting there too I think):

```
ssh host 'sed -i -f - /etc/mail/sendmail.mc' <<'SED_END'
s/dnl MASQUERADE_AS.*/MASQUERADE_AS(`domain.com')dnl/
SED_END
```

If the `sed` on the remote host can read a `sed` script from standard input using `-f -`, then this would probably work (otherwise, for example on some BSD systems, try `-f /dev/stdin`).

The command calls `sed` on the remote host and passes the `sed` editing script on standard input.  The `sed` script is single quoted due to the quotes in `'SED_END'`, so the shell won't be trying to expand things in its text.

I've also removed the trailing `$` in the regular expression as it's not needed (`.*` would match to the end of the line anyway).

A ever so slightly shorter `sed` script (just avoiding mentioning `MASQUERADE_AS` twice):

```sed
s/dnl \(MASQUERADE_AS\).*/\1(`domain.com')dnl/
```